# Why does Haskell NoBuffering option still seem to buffer?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I loaded up a file in ghci with the following:

```
h <- openFile "somefile.txt" ReadMode
hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
```

I then modified and saved somefile.txt in a text editor. When I call hGetChar several times in ghci, I receive the old characters of the file (as if the entire file was buffered when I opened it). I expected to calls of hGetChar to return the modified contents. Why is this not the case?

**Edit:**
The reason why it isn't showing the modified contents in the case decribed above is indeed because of the text editor. When the cat command is used instead (*cat > somefile.txt*), then the modified file contents is returned.

However, it does still seem to doing buffering. Say the file contents is as follows:

```
ABCDEFGHI
123456789
```

If I run hGetChar I get the 'A' as expected.

Now if I use cat (*cat > somefile.txt*) to change the contents to the following, and run hGetChar again, I would expect 'Z' but it's returning 'B':

```
AZZZZZZZZ
```

Comment: This is possible if your text editor writes to a temp file, then renames it over `somefile.txt`. In that case all existing handles would still refer to the (now nameless) old file.

Comment: Good point, I modified the question with a more specific scenario

Comment: How are you using `cat`? `cat` only writes to standard output, so it won't change the file unless you redirect stdout from `cat` to the file.

Comment: Yes, cat was redirected to the file: cat > somefile.txt

Comment: Did you try `hGetChar` one more time? [This](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#t:BufferMode) says "The hLookAhead operation implies that even a no-buffered handle may require a one-character buffer." If it is still behaving that way, I suspect there is buffering happening at the OS level and you might need to read the entire old file in before you can read the new data. I don't know much about that though, so hopefully someone more informed about that can answer.

Comment: @DavidYoung Trying on my computer it seems like the old contents are still returned, and after those the new contents are shown. If you `hSeek` at the beginning of the file you see the new contents.

Comment: Okay: trick to obtain the new contents: `pos <- hTell h; hSeek h pos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferMode` is only relevant when writing to a handle, not when reading from it.

From `[note Buffered Reading]` in [GHC.IO.Handle.Types](http://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/blob/ghc-8.0.1-release:/libraries/base/GHC/IO/Handle/Types.hs#l257):

```
Note that the buffering mode (haBufferMode) makes no difference when
reading data into a Handle.  When reading, we can always just read all
the data there is available without blocking, decode it into the Char
buffer, and then provide it immediately to the caller.
```

The documentation for input [BufferMode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#t:BufferMode) seems to be outdated.